# Is using variable as type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to know I should avoid this pattern `(b[firstCriteria] as number)`, I want the function to be type-safe and to only allow an existing key on the object inside the array to be passed

TypeScript is returning an error, and I found two ways basically

1. Add `[key: string]: number` to the type definition but this allows any key to be passed

   ```
   interface BaseHighLightsRes {
     id: number;
     manager_rank: number;
     player_name: string;
     entry_name: string;
     [key: string]: number;
   }
   ```
2. The second way is to add `as Number`

   ```
   import { BaseHighLightsRes } from "../types/apiResponce";

   export const sortHighlight = <T extends BaseHighLightsRes>(
     array: T[],
     firstCriteria: keyof T,
     secondCriteria: keyof T = "manager_rank"
   ): void => {
     array.sort(
       (a, b) =>
         (b[firstCriteria] as number) - (a[firstCriteria] as number) ||
         (a[secondCriteria] as number) - (b[secondCriteria] as number)
     );
   };
   ```

I don't know if my type is well-implemented, how to get TypeScript to correctly infer the type?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out what went wrong (with my code), but here's my attempt anyway.

`KeysOfType` type retrieves all keys with values of the given type from the given record. We use it to constrain `firstCriteria` and `secondCriteria` to only keys with `number` values. That way, when sorting and accessing these properties, we can be sure that they are of `number` type. But I kept getting errors, so I used `// @ts-ignore` to ignore all the errors. Since the code is not really complex, I think it might be okay.

**Resulting code:**

```
interface BaseHighLightsRes {
  id: number;
  manager_rank: number;
  player_name: string;
  entry_name: string;
}


type KeysOfType<TRecord extends Record<any, any>, TargetType> = { 
  [K in keyof TRecord]: TRecord[K] extends TargetType ? K : never 
}[keyof TRecord];

export const sortHighlight = <T extends BaseHighLightsRes>(
  array: T[],
  firstCriteria: KeysOfType<T, number>,
  // @ts-ignore
  secondCriteria: KeysOfType<T, number> = "manager_rank"
): void => {
  array.sort(
    (a, b) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      return b[firstCriteria] - a[firstCriteria] ||
      // @ts-ignore
        a[secondCriteria] - b[secondCriteria]
    }
  );
};

// okay
sortHighlight([{
  entry_name: 'fsdf',
  id: 123,
  manager_rank: 123,
  player_name: 'fsdf'
}], 'id', 'manager_rank');

// error! second arg is not assignable
sortHighlight([{
  entry_name: 'fsdf',
  id: 123,
  manager_rank: 123,
  player_name: 'fsdf'
}], 'player_name', 'manager_rank');
```

---

**Bonus type** (since I've written it and haven't used)
Generates a record type with only values of `TargetType`.

```
type RecordWithKeysOfType<TRecord extends Record<any, any>, TargetType> = Pick<TRecord, KeysOfType<TRecord, TargetType>>;
```